# 2D line styling not displaying in snapshots

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are implementing the 2D line style solution shown in the article https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-get-2d-line-style-view-3d-models

Once the styling is applied calling the viewer.getScreenshot() method the screenshot still displays the model in full colour.
Is there a parameter or setting needed to enable the screenshots to display with the styling currently in the viewer?

Thanks

Comment: I debugged getScreenshot, it looks it always goes to the render target of color, while 'setPostProcessParameter("style", "graphite")' seems to create another target. This might explain why the function always returns the colored result. Please bear with me checking with engineer team if they have any solutions

Answer (score 0):

our engineer team replied this looks like a limitation on the screenshot api, which doesn't take into consideration the NPR effects. We logged this with #LMV-3905.

With my experience, some 3rd party library might help to take snapshot of HTML DOM, one of which is http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ . The usage is straightforward. The picture below is what I tested. I am not clear where those three shadows come from, just for your reference. you might need to check with html2canvas.

```
html2canvas(Viewer.container).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas) 
});
```

[image]